# How to update mysql date column field with the next working day.?

Tags: php, android, mysqli

I want a mysql `DATE_ADD(date_field_column, interval ## ####)` method to jump on next working day.

```
Ex. Date1 = 10-07-2015  & Date2 = 20-07-2015
```

There are total 5 days working days `(Mon-Fri)` so I have a query that if date column has date `10-07-2015` then it should jump on 13-07-2015 as next working day.

Comment: You mean 5 working days, right?

Comment: yes.. monday-friday.. again no sat-sunday, agian monday-friday

Comment: Does the solution have to be in SQL or can you make the adjustments in PHP then update the record?

Comment: It wld be better if i get in sql.

Comment: MySQL has a DAYOFWEEK() function, you could check the day of week then add the appropriate number of days using DATE_ADD() -- do you need to cater for public holidays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
    IF(
       DAYOFWEEK(dat) = '6' OR DAYOFWEEK(dat) = '7' ,
       IF(DAYOFWEEK(dat)='6', DATE_ADD(dat, INTERVAL + 3 DAY), DATE_ADD(dat, INTERVAL + 2 DAY)),
       DATE_ADD(dat, INTERVAL + 1 DAY)
      ) AS newdat
```

I too had this requirement, however this won't work if your requirement would also include holidays. you then have to connect with your holiday master table and have to do it on application side.

Comment: and if i want only weekend days then?

Comment: @N.R.. if you consider only weekends(sat-sun),then  above query would work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Please use below code, this code will return you to date of next working day(exclude Saturday and Sunday).

I set example with `SELECT` statement so modify as per your requirement.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(
        '2015-07-10', INTERVAL 
                IF(DAYNAME('2015-07-10')  = 'Saturday', 2, 
                        IF(DAYNAME('2015-07-10')  = 'Friday', 3, 1)
                                ) DAY);
```

NOTE: Date format use for this example is YYYY-MM-DD.

Let me know if you face any query/concern regarding this.

Thanks!